# Error while trying to run a program to find primes within a given range in C

Tags: c, runtime-error, primes

This is a program in C to find all the prime numbers within a specified range.

```
#include<stdio.h>
void prime(int low,int high)
{
  int rem,a,b,g;
  printf("The prime numbers in this range are: \n");
  if(low==1)
  low++;
  if(low==0)
  low=low+2;
  for(a=low;a<=high;a++)
  {
    rem=1;
    for(b=2;b<a-1;b++)
    {
      g=a%b;
      rem=rem*g;
    }
    if(rem!=0)
    printf("%d \n",a);
  }
}
int main()
{
  int i,j;
  printf("Enter the lower limit of the range \n");
  scanf("%d",&i);
  printf("Enter the higher limit of the range \n");
  scanf("%d",&j);
  prime(i,j);
  return 0;
}
```

The program is being compiled without any problems but there is one runtime error as follows:

[image]

and line 29 is

```
prime(i,j);
```

And this is the rendered output:

[image]

Can someone tell me what is going wrong?

Comment: Doing `rem=rem*g;` is wasteful, especially when dealing with large numbers. Just check to see if `g` is 0 and break.

Comment: @Coldspeed Thanks for the suggestion. It is helpful. But the program is not running at all. Can you help with that?

Comment: Did you actually enter any values?

Comment: @kaylum No. I could not. As soon as I press the "Run" button to build the executable, it shows the above output and the runtime error message.

Comment: What system are you running on?  OS?  Compiler?

Comment: You probably don't have a terminal in your IDE, so there's nothing to read from for `stdin`, therefore `scanf()` doesn't convert anything and your variables remain uninitialized.

Comment: The posted code works as-is for me, compiled on gcc. Nice pic of young Erwin, btw :)

Comment: The code has *UB* if `scanf()` can't convert anything. Simple "solution": initialize `i` and `j`.

Comment: @Jack I am working in a PLATO IDE from silverfrost, on a Windows 10 computer.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat Your **IDE** seems to redirect `stdin` from somewhere, possibly `NUL` on windows, it doesn't matter -> you have *no* input to your `scanf()` calls. Try to run the compiled executable directly from a command-line window, it *should* work as expected. Still it has **undefined behavior** if you enter something that's not a number. See a [document I wrote on `scanf()`](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html) for details.

Comment: *Always* check program input, such as by testing the return value from `scanf`.

Comment: While others are answering your question, also note that even for small integers, the value of `rem` quickly overflows are reaches `0`. So, your code does not work as intended for numbers like `71` if your integer is of size 8 bytes.

Comment: @FelixPalmen It works if I initialise i and j. But the scanf is not working, as you said. I am reading your document. 2 things I want to ask you: in your first comment, what did you mean by "The code has UB if scanf() can't convert anything." And what do you mean by "Try to run the compiled executable directly from a command-line window"? Actually, I am not much acquainted with these terms.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat I try to explain these things in the linked document. For starters: you don't give `i` and `j` a value at declaration (aka *initialize* them), so their value is *indeterminate*. Using such a value is *undefined behavior*. `scanf()` *would* give them values, but if it doesn't find input that can be parsed in a number (as requested with `%d`), it just won't. It tells you by returning either `0` or `EOF`, but you ignore the return value.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat for your second question, just run "Command Prompt" (or `cmd.exe`) from your *start menu* on windows and `cd` to the directory you're compiling in, then run your compiled program by entering its name.

Comment: I have pinned `cmd.exe` to my start menu.

Comment: And by all means, do what @Coldspeed said.  You are getting overflow errors in the `rem=rem*g` line, and it is causing errors.  Apparently, `-2147483648 * 6 == 0`.

Comment: Also, you only need to go up to `sqrt(a)`, not `a-1`.  And if you are not going to keep a list of primes, just check 2, then every odd number above that.

Comment: This code compiles and works ok ( using gcc under linux) there is a problem with your input, what compiler settings and ide are you using ?

Comment: @CioacaRadu I am using PLATO IDE from silverfrost  and the compiler is ftn95. I don't know much about these.

Comment: Why in your console screenshot you haven't give any number as input for the range ?

Comment: @CioacaRadu please read the preceeding comments. It's *quite probably* the IDE's fault.

Comment: @CioacaRadu I cannot. As soon as I press "Enter" to run the program, the run time error message comes along with that output. I am not given a chance to input anything.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat Consider using either `msvc` (with "Visual Studio") or `gcc` (using `mingw`, possibly `msys2`) for compiling C code for windows.

Comment: @FelixPalmen My problem is still not resolved. I read your document in total. But none matches my problem. Also, I just copy-pasted the main function into a new file without the other function and it ran successfully. The other files also run smoothly. I don't think this is the IDE's fault.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat try inserting this line before the scanf statements: `fflush(stdin)` , it's just a try

Comment: @CioacaRadu this is *ill adviced*, `fflush(stdin)` is *undefined behavior*.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat the *very first example* in my document matches the problem in your code **exactly** and you already found out that you can fix that e.g. by initializing `i` and `j`. Your **IDE** not letting you interactively enter some input is an entirely different problem, so you really should run your compiled executable **outside** your ide (in `cmd.exe`).

Comment: @FelixPalmen Okay. You're right. But why is my IDE behaving like this, only for this program? The `scanf` works awesome in all the other programs that I have written.

Comment: @SchrodingersCat This of course is strange, I just assumed it doesn't allow interactive input at all. You'll have to wait for someone who actually *knows* "*PLATO IDE / ftn95*" to answer this ;) Or just use something more common like Microsoft's `msvc`/visual studio or `mingw`/`gcc`.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Fine, then. I'll wait. Thanks for helping, anyway. :)

Comment: @SchrodingersCat YW, but really, *if I were you*, I wouldn't wait. Did you try running your program directly from `cmd.exe`? If so, does it work? It *should*! :)

Comment: @FelixPalmen As I already told you, I am not that good at all these things. Truly speaking, I havent run command prompt before in windows, last time it was for DOS in about 2004 or 2003. I didn't know how to run the program. And finally when I tried to run it, it showed 14 compilation errors, many of which were just absurd ... I know that they are correct syntax. So it didn't run.

Comment: You shouldn't attempt to "run" the `.c` file but the `.exe` resulting from compilation (just a guess on what you're doing)

Comment: @FelixPalmen Well, thanks. Guess what, the program ran !! Correctly.

Comment: @FelixPalmen However, the problem remains. Since I have got an exam on Tuesday, there I may be given such a program to write. There I would have to do it in the IDE. Any tips for that one?

Comment: I really can't help on that with this compiler and IDE I don't know. But if the program works correctly outside the IDE, it's not the program's fault when it doesn't work from the IDE. I'd tell this to my instructor, it should be a quite convincing argument ...

Comment: the posted code has a logic problem!  when the low value is 1 and the high value is 11,  then the output is: 3, 5, 7, 11.   I.E. it skipped the number 2

Comment: @SchrodingersCat, please, PLEASE, when you edit your question DO NOT delete/replace your original code, just add your new code at the end. (you can add a separator if you like) Why? Any answer or comment posted regarding your original code **no longer makes sense**. You won't get shot for doing it once, but just understand why you shouldn't do it going forward.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Question revised accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, like I said, first one is free... Thank you for fixing it. It really mucks things up when the comments and answers no longer match the question `:)`

Answer (score 1):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. checks for errors
3. uses the same logic as the OPs code (which is wrong)
4. consistently indents the code for ease of readability and understanding.
5. separates code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) for readability via a single blank line.
6. uses meaningful variable names
7. rejects 2, even though that is a prime number

and now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // scanf(), printf(), perror()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE


void prime( int low, int high )
{
    int b;
    int g;
    int r;

    printf("The prime numbers in this range are: \n");

    for(int a=low; a<=high; a++)
    {
        r=0;
        for(b=2; b<a-1; b++)
        {
            g=a%b;

            if(g==0)
                break;

            r++;
        }

        if(r==a-3)
            printf("%d \n",a);
    }
}


int main( void )
{
    int low  =60;
    int high =80;

    printf("Enter the lower limit of the range \n");
    if( 1 != scanf("%d",&low) )
    {
        perror( "scanf for first number failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful

    printf("Enter the higher limit of the range \n");
    if( 1 != scanf("%d",&high) )
    {
        perror( "scanf for second number failed" );
        exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
    }

    // implied else, scanf successful

    if( low < 0 || low > high )
    {
        printf( "the numbers must be >= 0 and the first number: %d must be <= the second number: %d\n", low, high );
    }

    else
    {
        prime( low, high );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

however, if `prime()` is written as follows:

```
void prime( int low, int high )
{
    int b;
    int g;

    printf("The prime numbers in this range are: \n");

    for(int a=low; a<=high; a++)
    {
        for(b=2; b<a-1; b++)
        {
            if( !(g = (a%b) )
                break;
        }
            if( g )
                printf("%d \n",a);
    }
}
```

then the code works correctly (until certain overflow values are reached)

here is a run of the final corrected code:

```
Enter the lower limit of the range 
2
Enter the higher limit of the range 
11
The prime numbers in this range are: 
2 
3 
5 
7 
11
```

Comment: Thanks for your code and answer. However, my problem has been resolved. Please check the code that i have edited now. It is working absolutely fine. My previous code had a few problems, as you have already stated.

Answer (score 0):

My problem has been resolved, thanks to the beautiful and to-the-point comments that I have received. Special thanks to Felix Palmen, Coldspeed, Jack, Weather Vane and others whom I forgot to mention.

The final code, which works well and has no problem in running is as follows:

```
#include<stdio.h>
    void prime(int low,int high)
    {
      int a,b,g,r;
      printf("The prime numbers in this range are: \n");
      if(low==1)
      low++;
      if(low==0)
      low=low+2;
      for(a=low;a<=high;a++)
      {
        r=0;
        for(b=2;b<a;b++)
        {
          g=a%b;
          if(g==0)
          break;
          r++;
        }
        if(r==a-2)
        printf("%d \n",a);
      }
    }
    int main()
    {
      int i,j;
      printf("Enter the lower limit of the range \n");
      scanf("%d",&i);
      printf("Enter the higher limit of the range \n");
      scanf("%d",&j);
      prime(i,j);
      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: ??Works fine??   except when the user enters a alpha char or punctuation or the second value is less than the first value or either value is negative or any of the values is greater than 2gig or EOF is encountered or ...   NEVER trust the user to do the right thing.

Comment: there are only two valid signatures for `main()`   1) `int main( void )` and 2) `int main( int argc, char *argv[] )`   Note, when using `int main()` that is telling the compiler that any number of any type parameters might be entered, including no parameters.